# Pandas read_csv ignoring column dtypes when I pass skip_footer arg

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

When I try to import a csv file into a dataframe pandas (0.13.1) is ignoring the dtype parameter. Is there a way to stop pandas from inferring the data type on its own?

I am merging several CSV files and sometimes the customer contains letters and pandas imports  as a string. When I try to merge the two dataframes I get an error because I'm trying to merge two different types. I need everything stored as strings.

Data snippet:

```
|WAREHOUSE|ERROR|CUSTOMER|ORDER NO|
|---------|-----|--------|--------|
|3615     |     |03106   |253734  |
|3615     |     |03156   |290550  |
|3615     |     |03175   |262207  |
|3615     |     |03175   |262207  |
|3615     |     |03175   |262207  |
|3615     |     |03175   |262207  |
|3615     |     |03175   |262207  |
|3615     |     |03175   |262207  |
|3615     |     |03175   |262207  |
```

Import line:

```
df = pd.read_csv("SomeFile.csv", 
                 header=1,
                 skip_footer=1, 
                 usecols=[2, 3], 
                 dtype={'ORDER NO': str, 'CUSTOMER': str})
```

`df.dtypes` outputs this:

```
ORDER NO    int64
CUSTOMER    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I am using dtype as suggested in the answer there. It does not solve the problem.

Comment: 0.13.1 was not verbose in that you are falling back to the python parser because of ``usecols`` I think. and it is silently ignoring ``dtype``. Try using 0.14.0 it will a) work IIRC, b) will warn when this is happening (you can try forcing the engine with ``engine='c'``, at which point I think it will complain (even in 0.13.1)

Comment: 0.13.1 does not complain even with an explicit `engine='c'`. I updated to 0.14.1 and it still does not work but you are correct about it warning why. `ValueError: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support skip_footer, but this causes 'dtype' to be ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine. (Note the 'converters' option provides similar functionality.)`

Comment: ok, yeh, the warnings are better. another option is to explicity cast it, e.g. ``df['ORDER NO'] = df['ORDER NO'].astype(object)`` after creation.

Comment: I need to keep leading 0's since sometimes everything is imported as strings (if CUSTOMER contains X3615 for example). I guess I can just `df['CUSTOMER'] = df['CUSTOMER'].apply(lambda x: ('00000' + str(x))[-5:])` unless there is a better way

Comment: you can drop the ``skip_footer`` option and drop from the frame after (though this might cause dtype issues itself), you could also pre-filter to get rid of the footer. as an aside, you could help address those missing issues! (the dtype missing from the python engine is pretty easy actually)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Pandas 0.13.1 silently ignored the `dtype` argument because the `c engine` does not support `skip_footer`. This caused Pandas to fall back to the `python engine` which does not support `dtype`.

Solution? Use `converters`

```
df = pd.read_csv('SomeFile.csv', 
                 header=1,
                 skip_footer=1, 
                 usecols=[2, 3], 
                 converters={'CUSTOMER': str, 'ORDER NO': str},
                 engine='python')
```

Output:

```
In [1]: df.dtypes
Out[2]:
CUSTOMER    object
ORDER NO    object
dtype: object

In [3]: type(df['CUSTOMER'][0])
Out[4]: str

In [5]: df.head()
Out[6]:
  CUSTOMER ORDER NO
0    03106   253734
1    03156   290550
2    03175   262207
3    03175   262207
4    03175   262207
```

Leading 0's from the original file are preserved and all data is stored as strings.

Comment: How can I use converters to achieve the same thing but for all the columns and without specifying each column name?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately using converters or newer pandas versions doesn't solve the more general problem of always ensuring that read_csv doesn't infer a float64 dtype. With pandas 0.15.2, the following example, with a CSV containing integers in hexadecimal notation with NULL entries, shows that using converters for what the name implies they should be used for, interferes with dtype specification.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a = ["0xff", "0xfe"], b = ["0xfd", None], c = [None, "0xfc"], d = [None, None]))
In [2]: df.to_csv("H:/tmp.csv", index = False)
In [3]: ef = pd.read_csv("H:/tmp.csv", dtype = {c: object for c in "abcd"}, converters = {c: lambda x: None if x == "" else int(x, 16) for c in "abcd"})
In [4]: ef.dtypes.map(lambda x: x)
Out[4]:
a      int64
b    float64
c    float64
d     object
dtype: object
```

The specified dtype of object is only respected for the all-NULL column. In this case, the float64 values can just be converted to integers, but by the pigeon hole principle, not all 64 bit integers can be represented as a float64.

The best solution I have found for this more general case is to get pandas to read potentially problematic columns as strings, as already covered, then convert the slice with values that need conversion (and not mapping the conversion on the column, as that will again result in an automatic dtype = float64 inference).

```
In [5]: ff = pd.read_csv("H:/tmp.csv", dtype = {c: object for c in "bc"}, converters = {c: lambda x: None if x == "" else int(x, 16) for c in "ad"})
In [6]: ff.dtypes
Out[6]:
a     int64
b    object
c    object
d    object
dtype: object
In [7]: for c in "bc":
   .....:     ff.loc[~pd.isnull(ff[c]), c] = ff[c][~pd.isnull(ff[c])].map(lambda x: int(x, 16))
   .....:
In [8]: ff.dtypes
Out[8]:
a     int64
b    object
c    object
d    object
dtype: object
In [9]: [(ff[c][i], type(ff[c][i])) for c in ff.columns for i in ff.index]
Out[9]:
[(255, numpy.int64),
 (254, numpy.int64),
 (253L, long),
 (nan, float),
 (nan, float),
 (252L, long),
 (None, NoneType),
 (None, NoneType)]
```

As far as I have been able to determine, at least up to version 0.15.2 there is no way to avoid postprocessing of string values in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer from Ripster above solved the OP's problem. But for me, though this may seem obvious to some, my problem was that the header/column names in my CVS were all upper case and I had them as lower case in my dtype={...} in the code. Switched them all to upper case, and read_csv stopped ignoring my explicit typing. SQL is my native language, and there, in most cases, the case of column names does not matter. There's a couple hours I won't get back...